# Verify existance of all combinations in table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, combinations

I want to write a query for oracle that verifies if all combinations exist in a table.
My problem is that the "key-columns" of the table are FKs linked to other tables, which means that the combinations are based on the rows of the other tables.

ERD example:
[image] 

So, if there are 3 rows (1-3) in table A, 4 rows in table B and 2 rows in table C, MyTable must have these rows (3x4x2, 24 totally):

```
id, a_fk, b_fk, c_fk, someValue
x, 1, 1 ,1, ..
x, 1, 1, 2, ..
x, 1, 2, 1, ..
x, 1, 2, 2, ..
x, 1, 3, 1, ..
x, 1, 3, 2, ..
..............
```

I am not sure how to write this, because the available data of the combination may change.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you trying to query all the combinations you do have, or identify any missing combinations, or get a simple yes/no flag to say if any are missing?

Comment: Identifying missing combinations/getting a yes/no flag. Both options are good enough.

Comment: The option matters from a performance perspective. If a yes/no flag is all you need, then a query with an EXISTS or NOT IN will short circuit out on the first TRUE. If a list is needed then the best approach may depend on available indexes. Performance may not seem a big deal on small data sets, but getting used to best practices from a performance perspective is a good habit to get into for when the day comes that the real world throws a couple of million (or hundreds of millions) of rows at you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can identify all the possible combinations with [cross joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#BABGHCBD), which generate the cartesian product of the rows:

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id
from tablea a
cross join tableb b
cross join tablec c
```

Depending on the exact result you want, you can use that in various ways to see what you do or do not have. To list the combinations that don't exist, use [the `minus` set operator](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators005.htm):

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id
from tablea a
cross join tableb b
cross join tablec c
minus
select fk_a, fk_b, fk_c
from my_table mt;
```

Or you can use `not exists` instead of minus, as other answers show.

If you want to list them all with the main table's column if it exists, and null otherwise, you can use a left outer join:

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id, mt.id
from tablea a
cross join tableb b
cross join tablec c
left join my_table mt
on mt.fk_a = a.id and mt.fk_b = b.id and mt.fk_c = c.id
```

You can also count the results from the first query, and then use that in a `case` statement to get a simple yes/no answer to show whether all combinations exist. And so on - it really depends what you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

To get possible combinations, cross join works.

So you can get your 24 rows with:

```
with a as (
    select 1 id1 from dual union all
    select 2 id1 from dual union all
    select 3 id1 from dual )
  , b as (
    select 1 id2 from dual union all
    select 2 id2 from dual union all
    select 3 id2 from dual union all
    select 4 id2 from dual )   
  , c as (
    select 1 id3 from dual union all
    select 2 id3 from dual )
select id1, id2, id3 
from a cross join b cross join c;
```

From there it is a pretty easy step to look for the combinations that do or do not exist in your table. To get the combinations that aren't in the target table you could:

```
with a as (
    select 1 id1 from dual union all
    select 2 id1 from dual union all
    select 3 id1 from dual )
  , b as (
    select 1 id2 from dual union all
    select 2 id2 from dual union all
    select 3 id2 from dual union all
    select 4 id2 from dual )   
  , c as (
    select 1 id3 from dual union all
    select 2 id3 from dual )
  , t as ( 
     select 1 id1, 1 id2, 1 id3 from dual union all
     select 1 id1, 1 id2, 2 id3 from dual union all
     select 1 id1, 2 id2, 1 id3 from dual union all
     select 1 id1, 2 id2, 2 id3 from dual union all
     select 1 id1, 3 id2, 1 id3 from dual union all
     select 1 id1, 4 id2, 2 id3 from dual )
select lst.id1, lst.id2, lst.id3
from (  
    select id1, id2, id3 
    from a cross join b cross join c ) lst
where not exists (select 1 from t
                  where t.id1 = lst.id1 
                    and t.id2 = lst.id2
                    and t.id3 = lst.id3)
```

Or, use the NOT IN test:

```
select lst.id1, lst.id2, lst.id3
from (  
    select id1, id2, id3 
    from a cross join b cross join c ) lst
where (id1, id2, id3) not IN (select distinct id1, id2, id3  from t)
```

Alex's minus does the same thing, all coming up with the same result set - and which option will work best may depend on the number of records in the composite table, available indexes, and - most importantly - exactly what it is you want.

If you just want to know that there is one or more missing combinations, then use an option that short-circuits out as quickly as possible. EXISTS, for example, will stop checking the moment it hits a case that evaluates to TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to get Cartesian product of the sets of records from your three (or more) tables and apply a `NOT EXISTS` clause giving you those rows (in the output) that are not present in `mytable`.

```
select a.id, b.id, c.id
from tbla a cross join tblb b cross join tblc c
where not exists (
  select 1
  from mytable t
  where t.fk_a = a.id
    and t.fk_b = b.id
    and t.fk_c = c.id
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

so, total number of rows in MyTable should be equal to multiplication of total rows in other tables, you can try like this:

```
select
case when (select count(*) from MyTable) =
((select count(*) from TableA) * (select count(*) from TableB)... )
then 'Everything is fine'
else 'Some rows are missing' end
from dual
```

this will work only if you have unique constraint on (fk_a, fk_b, fc_...)

in case you don't have, you can use distinct

```
select
case when (select count(distinct concat(fk_a, fk_b,....)) from MyTable) =
((select count(*) from TableA) * (select count(*) from TableB)... )
then 'Everything is fine'
else 'Some rows are missing' end
from dual
```

Comment: I tried to run this query, but I got: `ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: @kordirko my query is just example, you cannot run it, have you modified it to meet your actual structure?

Comment: Ok, I replaced `if...then...else` with `SELECT CASE WHEN ....... THEN 'Everything is fine'
else 'Some rows are missing' end FROM dual` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This won't get the right answer if there is more than one ow in `my_table` with the same combination of a, b and c.

Comment: @AlexPoole yep, updating